# Send Jquery value to php file?

Tags: php, jquery

I have a file called post-blog.php this is collecting the data and storing it in a variable called page.

```
var page = title + content+ image + datetime +categories;
```

I'm then sending this off to publish.php, if sent correctly send the user to that page.

```
  $.ajax({
        type:   'POST',
        cache:    false,
        url:      'publish.php',
        data:     page,
        success:  function( page ) {

          alert(page);
          window.location.href = "publish.php";

        }

      });

      return false;
```

This I my php script which is on the 2nd page (publish.php). How can I store the jquery data into php varible. So that I can display them on publish page.

```
<?php
if ( $_POST['page'] == true )
{
   echo "Inserted";
}
?>
```

Comment: You want to let the user build a page and than view it? To view it, just have publish.php echo out the resulting html and put that html on to the current page. Be sure to strip out any malicious tags/data

Comment: Ah that seems like a better solution, problem is i cant get the php to display variables

Answer (score 0):

you can pass your variable like this

```
var page = {
    title : title,
    content : content,
    image : image ,
    datetime : datetime ,
    categories : categories 
}
```

and then in php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["title"])){  // you can use content , image ,... same way
    $title = $_POST["title"];
    echo $title;
}
?>
```

and in ajax

```
success:  function( response) { //response is the data which returned from php .. for sure (page) will work but just to be clear
          alert(response);
          //window.location.href = "publish.php";
        }
```

if you want to use page as an array you can use

```
var page = [];
page.push(title);
page.push(content);
.......
```

then in php use

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['page'])) {
  print_r($_POST['page']);
}
?>
```

Comment: It seems like he wants to let the user create some content and than show the finished product to the user on publish.php. He needs to either display the content on the page he is on or submit a form with the data to publish.php.

Comment: @Terminus We didn't get any response from him yet .. but I answered the question depending on what he request is.. for sure when he reply we will know what he want exactly .. still waiting for him :)

Comment: Thank you for all your responses, I'm having no luck with these answers. Been trying to figure this out all day. What I'm trying to do is i've got a form and all the data is saving to these variables. I then want to display this in a page. So the user can see what there page is going to like. Like what @terminus said. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @RH so terminus is right .. for that you should update your answer with your form html .. and just let us know if you include jquery or not?

Comment: I've included Jquery too shall i post that and the html form? cheers

Comment: @RH look you need to (1)submit the form and  (2)get your data from it and (3)pass them to php then return it (4)back to ajax success callback function .. that is the mechanism of what you trying to do .. in which part you got a problem??

Comment: @RH so your objective is to display the data from the form on publish.php. Use jquery to validate the form but instead of $.ajax, just submit the form to publish.php. Than you will be able to display the data without any fancy JS. Update your question with the html form so we can help more

Answer (score 0):

You can send this by setting data as follow:

```
 data: {'page': page},
```

jQuery has some examples on the $.ajax and $.post page:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Answer (score 0):

You can send data using query string variable in url like this

```
$.ajax({
        type:   'POST',
        cache:    false,
        url:      'publish.php',
        data:     page,
        success:  function( page ) {
          alert(page);
          window.location.href = "publish.php" + "?page=" + page ;
        }
      });

  return false;
```

Then on publishing page you could get data using following code

```
if (isset($_POST['page']) &&  $_POST['page'] != '') {
 var_dump($_POST['page']);
 echo 'inserted';}
?>
```